# Is there a simple solution to this (ordinary) differential equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm trying to solve the following differential equation:

$$ \frac{dy}{dx} = - \frac{3x + 2y}{2y}. $$

It looks pretty simple, yet it's not separable, linear, or exact.  It is of the form

$$ \frac{dy}{dx} = f(y/x). $$

I could do the substitution $v = y/x$, and I know it would look pretty ugly, but is there a better or simpler method?

Comment: Doubt it: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y%27%28x%29+%3D+-%283x%2B2y%29%2F%282y%29

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way I can think is to solve:
$$
\frac{dy}{dt} = -3 x - 2y \\
\frac{dx}{dt} = 2 y
$$
say by matrix exponentiation. Then one can invert $ x(t) $ to find $ y(x) $.

Comment: For the qualitative end behavior of the solution, I like the matrix solution.  The associated matrix is
$$\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 2 \\ -3 & -2 \end{pmatrix},$$
which leads to the eigenvalues $-1 \pm i\sqrt{5}$.  So I can have overall sense of the family of solutions. In particular, I can tell that they must "go" through the origin.